# Can't access user messages in django-userena

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I m working on django-userena project. when i run the demo project, everything is working great except the user message system. whenever i try to access the user messages link, it gives me "reverse match" error! i tried everything but didn't get pass through it!

**Error message**

```
NoReverseMatch at /messages/
Reverse for 'userena_umessages_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['messages/view/(?P<username>[\\.\\w]+)/$']

Error during template rendering
In template /home/mach/userena/django-userena/demo/demo/templates/umessages/message_list.html, error at line 21
```

CODE:

```
11  <ul id="messages" class="list-view">
12    {% for message in message_list %}
13    <li>
14    {% if message.from_user == user %}
15    <a href="{% url 'userena_umessages_detail' message.to_user.username %}">
16    <img src="{{ message.to_user.profile.get_mugshot_url }}" class="avatar" />
17    {{ message.to_user }}
18  
19    {% get_unread_message_count_between user and message.to_user as unread_between_count %}
20    {% else %}
21    <a href="{% url 'userena_umessages_detail' message.from_user.username %}">
22    <img src="{{ message.from_user.profile.get_mugshot_url }}" class="avatar" />
23    {{ message.from_user }}
24  
25    {% get_unread_message_count_between user and message.from_user as unread_between_count %}
26    {% endif %}
27    <p>{{ message.latest_message }}</p> <p class="date">({{ unread_between_count }} new )</p>
28      </a>
29    </li>
30    {% endfor %}
31  </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

add "`um_`" before "`to_user`" and "`from_user`" as in [this example](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/contrib/umessages/templates/umessages/message_list.html).